# Cordova HTML5 iOS video wont play

Tags: ios, html, cordova, video, html5-video

I have a very basic project (the vanilla cordova project with the html added):

```
<video src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
```

But I can't get this to work. This is what I see, a cancelled play icon:

[image]

How can I get this to work properly? If I want to use a locally referenced file, is this possible? Also can it play in the `<video>` box and not full screen?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [whitelisted the video's domain](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)?

Cordova has a security model that blocks, by default, every external resource request. You can allow this domain adding:

```
<access origin="http://download.blender.org/" />
```

to your `config.xml` file.